# Open two .csv file code - one file opens the other does not

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lines of code that open two different .csv files one works and one does not. (the CodeMapping.csv file opens, the ValidationMapping.csv does not)

```
import pandas as pd

codeMapping = pd.read_csv('C:\Database\CodeMapping.csv')
validationMap = pd.read_csv('C:\Database\ValidationsMapping.csv')
```

Both lines are next to each other in the scipt and both files are at the path specified, I just can't figure this out......

Comment: Please post the full error message

Comment: Hi Dan, there is no error message the code just stops

Comment: Of course the code stops--what you've posted doesn't actually output anything.

Comment: Are you able to open the same from console or file explorer. Just make sure there is no spelling mistake in filenames. Also are you able to open the second file first.

Comment: so `codeMapping.shape` has values but `validationMap.shape` returns...?

Comment: codeMapping.shape: (62, 17), I can't get a shape for the validationMap (the code stops.....)

Comment: "the code stops..." are you sure? I think either it errors or it returns something, that something might be `None`. Is `validationMap is None` true? Also, did you try only reading ValidationsMapping as Nand suggested? Or are you suggesting that the Python interpreter crashes and closes at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is your backslashes.  You should escape them:

```
codeMapping = pd.read_csv('C:\\Database\\CodeMapping.csv')
validationMap = pd.read_csv('C:\\Database\\ValidationsMapping.csv')
```